# How, if possible, can I use Swift 2.3 in the Mac OS terminal while Swift 3.0 is installed?

Tags: swift, terminal

I have a Swift file written in Swift 2.3 and I would like to execute via the Mac OS terminal.

```
swift foo.swift
```

However, my current version of Swift is 3.0 and when I run the above command it generates errors, because it assumes the code is written in Swift 3.0.

Is it possible to run Swift 2.3 code in the terminal while Swift 3.0 is installed? And if so how?

Comment: Yes it is possible.